# Cross region replication of Google Cloud Postgresql instances

Tags: postgresql, replication, google-cloud-sql, database-replication

From my understanding of their documentation, the cloud postgresql service, being beta, does not yet support external replicas, which is what i thought i could use if i wanted a database to be replicated cross region.

This could very well end up being a blocker for our setup, since we need the data in separate regions.

I thought i'd investigate all the streaming replication options out there, and perhaps find one that does not require touching the host folder or custom config wise, which in my mind would end up looking like

`master => streaming_replication_app => slave`

but what from I've researched so far, no real streaming replication options are possible that are non intrusive.

Can you guys confirm or deny this and point me in the right direction? 
I need to decide if the Cloud postgres is too limited as a solution or not

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel

Comment: Did you ever find a solution/work around for this ?

Comment: @anilit99 We went with our own pg instances, deployed on kubernetes, replicated along the VPC. They've been running fairly stable ever since

Answer (score 0):

Cross region replica is supported in Google Cloud Sql.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/introducing-cross-region-replica-for-cloud-sql

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32348303)